# Use of ground beef in Chinese food

Tags: chinese-cuisine, ground-beef

I rarely see ground beef used in many Chinese or American Chinese food recipes. Is there just a small number of uses for ground beef in the Chinese kitchen?

Comment: Not enough for answer but I can think of several Sichuan dishes off the top off my head: ma po doufu, ants climbing a tree and some versions of Dan Dan noodles. I'm sure there's plenty more from the myriad regions of China.

Comment: You can find ground meat in dumplings and baozi (i don't know the english for it), a bun with meat inside of it

Answer (score 5):

Ground beef does not work well in any traditional stir-fry or soupy dish, though there are probably one or two that actually call for it

But it does work well, and is actually used in China for stuffed items. Some deep fried or steamed pastry rolls ("dim sum") or steamed buns have some ground beef in the filling

In my experience it was a very coarse grind, and unlike the typical western butchery grind

I have seen a form of a "scotch egg", and hard boiled egg, wrapped with a smooth layer of chilies, herbs, and ground beef, and baked until set. Served cold, but very hot!

It is also used for some kinds of BBQ skewers (kebab style), more predominantly in the Muslim areas (which are limited). Some skewers are actual edible vegetables; like stems of choy sum, or a sort of asparagus etc. All very nice!

Of course, you can get all this in Pork, Chicken, Lamb, Goat, or whatever else moves in China

**Examples**

[image: Beef Roll]

Beef Roll (like an English 'Sausage Roll' with light pastry)

[image: Beef "String"]

Beef "String" (on right, like middle eastern kebab, but totally different herb taste)

[image: Beef Steamed Bun]

Beef Steamed Bun

Comment: dim sum is familiar territory, and as an armenian beef kebabs are like second nature, but the edible skewers is an interesting idea

Answer (score 3):

Well, traditionally Chinese (*I mean ethnic Chinese not Chinese nationality*) doesn't eat beef. That why it is uncommon to see beef as ingredients in Chinese recipes. A lot of traditional Chinese recipe that do use beef are because of the influences from the Mongolian.

Answer (score 0):

It's not terribly uncommon, at least in American/Chinese food. [Images](https://www.google.com/search?q=chinese+ground+beef&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=Qo-SU6eVIcv9oAS9toKYCA&ved=0CE0QsAQ&biw=1536&bih=731). It's homey, and doesn't necessarily make for a pretty plate, but the flavors can be quite solid.

Ground beef is particularly good in egg rolls or dumplings. Ground pork is more commonly seen (at least here), but ground beef is *tasty* that way.